# How to specify a client certificate to psql?

Tags: ssl-certificate, postgresql, psql

I have a Postgres server with a user `dev` which requires a client certificate to log in. I'm using the command `psql "sslmode=require user=dev host=db.prod"`, which gives me `psql: FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate`.

I know where the certificate is on my server. My question is, how do I specify the client certificate location to `psql`?

Comment: See https://www.howtoforge.com/postgresql-ssl-certificates

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-ssl.html#LIBPQ-SSL-CLIENTCERT

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated in the documentation linked by @Milen, you can do this by setting the `PGSSLCERT` and `PGSSLKEY` environment variables, or by adding `sslcert=<cert location> sslkey=<key location>` to the connection string.

Comment: I'll note here that `PGSSLCERT` and `PGSSLKEY` also allow ***paths*** to be specified, so don't `cat` the certificate or key itself into those variables.

Answer (score 23):

The end result looks like
`$>psql "port=5431 host=localhost user=postgres sslcert=./test/client.crt sslkey=./test/client.key sslrootcert=./test/server.crt sslmode=verify-ca"`

All the variables are [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-envars.html).

Comment: if I place root crt in ~/.postgreqsl/ I don't have to provide any key. If I place it somewhere else and provide sslrootcert, suddenly I have to also provide key - do you know how does that work?